# PHP - array comparison == and ===

Tags: php, arrays

Can someone clarify please why is the result of

```
$a = array (0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3);
$b = array (1 => 2, 2 => 3, 0 => 1); 
var_dump ($a === $b);
```

Boolean false and not Boolean true?

Comment: The order is not the same: http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [PHP manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.array.php)

> `$a === $b`: TRUE if $a and $b have the same key/value pairs in the same order and of the same types.

Your arrays key/value pairs are not set in the same order so the result will be `false`

Comment: Didn't know that order of the arrays is compared too, thanks.

Comment: No, it was someone else.

Answer (score 0):

Double equals compare only values, and triple equals compare datatype also

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array (0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3);
$b = array (1 => 2, 2 => 3, 0 => 1); 
$c = array (0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3);
var_dump( $a === $b );  // False
var_dump( $a === $c );  // True
```

The arrays must match, same order.

Answer (score 0):

$a === $b   will be TRUE **only if** $a and $b have the **same key/value** pairs in the **same order** and of the **same types**.

Answer (score 0):

```
$a == $b Equal TRUE if $a is equal to $b, except for (True == -1) which is still True.

$a === $b Identical TRUE if $a is equal to $b, and they are of the same type.
```

e.g.

> > "1" == 1; True
> >     "1" === 1; False

Comment: yeah who is this ?

Answer (score 0):

```
$a = array (0 => 1, 1 => 2, 2 => 3);
$b = array (1 => 2, 2 => 3, 0 => 1); 
var_dump($a == $b); // bool(true)
var_dump($a === $b); // bool(false)
```

`==` compares the variable from `$a with $b`
`===` compares the same datatypes from `$a with $b`